# Cannot write to S3 using AWS Batch with docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I created a job for AWS batch, with execution role `ecsTaskExecutionRole` that contains access like `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`, but a simple function using `boto3` to call `client.put_object` gives the following access error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

How should I solve this? I do not find anywhere else I could add other roles aside from the execution role when creating the job definition.

P.S. I can get away with this by setting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` but I guess that is probably bad practice.

Comment: Does the bucket have a bucket policy?

Comment: It has "block all public access -> on", but I don't know if my own access here is public or private access. Otherwise, I just used the default setting when I created the bucket from S3 web UI